There is an error in the computation of my energy consumption calculator in c++
My problem is that even my calculation is correct the output that it show is wrong. The only correct here is the " Hour " but the " Day, Week, Month " output is wrong it always fall short to the correct answer.
const double FACTOR_RATE = 0.0097822; // PHP per watt-hour

case 1:
    watts = 3950;
    applianceName = "A/C Floor Stand non inverter 4.5 HP";
    cout << "You chose 1. A/C Floor Stand non inverter 4.5HP 3950 watts" << endl;
    break;

costPerHour = watts * FACTOR_RATE;             // PHP per hour
costPerDay = costPerHour * hoursPerDay;        // PHP per day
costPerWeek = costPerDay * daysPerWeek;        // PHP per week
costPerMonth = costPerWeek * weeksPerMonth;    // PHP per month



Here is the full view of my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <limits> // For numeric_limits

using namespace std;

// Function to validate integer input within a specific range
int validateInput(int min, int max, const string& prompt) {
    int value;
    while (true) {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> value;

        // Check for input failure (e.g., non-integer input)
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear(); // Clear the error flag
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Discard invalid input
            cout << "Invalid input. Please enter an integer value." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        // Check if the input is within the valid range
        if (value < min || value > max) {
            cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a value between " << min << " and " << max << "." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        // Valid input
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Discard any remaining input
        return value;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Constants
    const double FACTOR_RATE = 0.0097822; // PHP per watt-hour

    // Variables for login
    string username, password;

    // Variables for menu choices
    char mainChoice;
    int categoryChoice;

    // Variables for appliance details
    double watts = 0.0;
    string applianceName = "";

    // Variables for usage inputs
    int hoursPerDay, daysPerWeek, weeksPerMonth;

    // Variables for cost calculations
    double costPerHour, costPerDay, costPerWeek, costPerMonth;

    // ------------------------------
    // Simple Login Section
    // ------------------------------
    cout << "Welcome to Meralco Electricity Calculator" << endl;
    cout << "Log In" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your username: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";
    cin >> password;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Hello, " << username << "!" << endl << endl;

    // ------------------------------
    // Main Menu Section
    // ------------------------------
    cout << "To begin the calculation, choose one of the categories below." << endl;
    cout << "A. Airconditioner" << endl;
    cout << "B. Computer and Gadgets" << endl;
    cout << "C. Kitchen Appliances" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice (A/B/C): ";
    cin >> mainChoice;
    cout << endl;

    // Convert mainChoice to uppercase for consistency
    mainChoice = toupper(mainChoice);

    // ------------------------------
    // Category Selection Section
    // ------------------------------
    switch (mainChoice) {
    case 'A':
        cout << "You chose Airconditioner" << endl;
        cout << "1. A/C Floor Stand non inverter 4.5HP 3950 watts" << endl;
        cout << "2. A/C Floor Split type inverter 1.00 HP 800 watts" << endl;
        cout << "3. A/C Floor Split type inverter 1.50 HP 1100 watts" << endl;
        cout << "4. A/C Floor Split type inverter 2.0 HP 1500 watts" << endl;
        cout << "5. A/C Floor Split type inverter 2.50HP 2300 watts" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the airconditioner category (1-5): ";
        cin >> categoryChoice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (categoryChoice) {
        case 1:
            watts = 3950;
            applianceName = "A/C Floor Stand non inverter 4.5 HP";
            cout << "You chose 1. A/C Floor Stand non inverter 4.5HP 3950 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            watts = 800;
            applianceName = "A/C Floor Split type inverter 1.00 HP";
            cout << "You chose 2. A/C Floor Split type inverter 1.00 HP 800 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            watts = 1100;
            applianceName = "A/C Floor Split type inverter 1.50 HP";
            cout << "You chose 3. A/C Floor Split type inverter 1.50 HP 1100 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            watts = 1500;
            applianceName = "A/C Floor Split type inverter 2.0 HP";
            cout << "You chose 4. A/C Floor Split type inverter 2.0 HP 1500 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            watts = 2300;
            applianceName = "A/C Floor Split type inverter 2.50HP";
            cout << "You chose 5. A/C Floor Split type inverter 2.50HP 2300 watts" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Enter correct number." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case 'B':
        cout << "You chose Computer and Gadgets" << endl;
        cout << "1. Printer 478 watts" << endl;
        cout << "2. Router 110 watts" << endl;
        cout << "3. Scanner 11 watts" << endl;
        cout << "4. Laptop 60 watts" << endl;
        cout << "5. Desktop Standard 65 watts" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the computer or gadget category (1-5): ";
        cin >> categoryChoice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (categoryChoice) {
        case 1:
            watts = 478;
            applianceName = "Printer";
            cout << "You chose 1. Printer 478 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            watts = 110;
            applianceName = "Router";
            cout << "You chose 2. Router 110 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            watts = 11;
            applianceName = "Scanner";
            cout << "You chose 3. Scanner 11 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            watts = 60;
            applianceName = "Laptop";
            cout << "You chose 4. Laptop 60 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            watts = 65;
            applianceName = "Desktop Standard";
            cout << "You chose 5. Desktop Standard 65 watts" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Enter correct number." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case 'C':
        cout << "You chose Kitchen Appliances" << endl;
        cout << "1. Induction cooker 1500 watts" << endl;
        cout << "2. Refrigerator French 193 watts" << endl;
        cout << "3. Rice cooker 3L 1000 watts" << endl;
        cout << "4. Washing Machine FrontLoad 2000 watts" << endl;
        cout << "5. Smart LED 15 watts" << endl;
        cout << "Enter the kitchen appliance category (1-5): ";
        cin >> categoryChoice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (categoryChoice) {
        case 1:
            watts = 1500;
            applianceName = "Induction cooker";
            cout << "You chose 1. Induction cooker 1500 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            watts = 193;
            applianceName = "Refrigerator French";
            cout << "You chose 2. Refrigerator French 193 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            watts = 1000;
            applianceName = "Rice cooker 3L";
            cout << "You chose 3. Rice cooker 3L 1000 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            watts = 2000;
            applianceName = "Washing Machine FrontLoad";
            cout << "You chose 4. Washing Machine FrontLoad 2000 watts" << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            watts = 15;
            applianceName = "Smart LED";
            cout << "You chose 5. Smart LED 15 watts" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Enter correct number." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Enter correct number." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

    // ------------------------------
    // Input Usage Details Section
    // ------------------------------
    // Validate hours per day (0-24)
    hoursPerDay = validateInput(0, 24, "Enter the number of hours used per day: ");

    // Validate days per week (1-7)
    daysPerWeek = validateInput(1, 7, "Enter the number of days used per week (1-7): ");

    // Validate weeks per month (1-4)
    weeksPerMonth = validateInput(1, 4, "Enter the number of weeks used per month (1-5): ");
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl << endl;

    // ------------------------------
    // Cost Calculation Section
    // ------------------------------
    // Calculate cost based on watt-hours
    costPerHour = watts * FACTOR_RATE;             // PHP per hour
    costPerDay = costPerHour * hoursPerDay;        // PHP per day
    costPerWeek = costPerDay * daysPerWeek;        // PHP per week
    costPerMonth = costPerWeek * weeksPerMonth;    // PHP per month

    // ------------------------------
    // Output Results Section
    // ------------------------------
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Appliance: " << applianceName << endl;
    cout << "Wattage: " << watts << " watts" << endl;
    cout << "Usage: " << hoursPerDay << " hours/day for " << daysPerWeek << " days/week and " << weeksPerMonth << " weeks/month" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Cost per hour: PHP " << costPerHour << endl;
    cout << "Cost per day: PHP " << costPerDay << endl;
    cout << "Cost per week: PHP " << costPerWeek << endl;
    cout << "Cost per month: PHP " << costPerMonth << endl;

    return 0;
}



The sample that i tried is
Appliance: 1. A/C Floor Stand non inverter 4.5HP 3950 watts
Hour: 6
Day: 7
Week: 4
The output that it always show is
Hour: 38.64 // THE ONLY CORRECT ANSWER //
Day: 231.84
Week: 1622.87
Month: 6491.47
The output that is correct and what I expect is
Hour: 38.64
Day: 231.87
Week: 1623.06
Month: 6492.24

Please read [mcve] and see What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

For a good StackOverflow question, you probably should have reduced the code to 15 lines or less removing all input and the menu system completely and using fixed values so that the focus of the question is the calculation and not your assignment. Remember the StackOverflow is not a user support forum. The #1 purpose of your question is to help future readers understand and fix the calculation problem.

Here is what I meant about a minimal example: https://ideone.com/0EsTUF

There is no error in your code...
Following the execution of your program, you come to the very end with following variables
watts = 3950
FACTOR_RATE = 0.0097822
hoursPerDay = 6

So, costPerDay = 231.838 which is rounded to costPerDay = 231.84 for the following line:
cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

Why do u expect a different result?
Note: Please, don't use cin in multiple function, use that in your main to get all user input u need and invoke functions for computation only (Single-responsibility principle).

Thank you for answering sir there is a basis on the sample output that given to us the expected output is this one
Hour: 38.64
Day: 231.87 Week: 1623.06 Month: 6492.24 I follow all the instruction but i cant figure out how to show the exact number similar to what we instructed to do

Hi. I understood your problem, but actually something is wrong in calculations, not in your program. If you would try doing calculations with pen and paper, the correct result is the one you computed, not the "exact number" they gave you. Are u sure about FACTOR_RATE value, or did u round it? Do "watts" is correct or just an approximation?

yes the factor rate is the value in the instruction the project is based on this website https://appliancecalculator.meralco.com.ph/ the input on the website is average montly bill: 5000, hour 6, day 7, week 4, the only missing on my code is the average monthly bill but i try it and the output is the same. the instruction doesnt have a average montly bill so im left with hour day week only

Hi. I don't know how these things work, but actually the problem is not a code problem. If u try doing calculations with values you are using in your program (cout<<3950 * 0.0097822 * 6, the values of watts, FACTOR_RATE and hoursPerDay), the result is the one I reported above. So the problem is not in your code (for implicit casting... just to say) but in formulas / values u used. Please check your formulas and update your code

I agree with @Roci49. 3950 * 0.0097822 * 6 is not 231.87 and I just tested it with  windows calculator in standard mode. Instead I get 231.83814
